# I want these lines to run FOR ALL of the values of my database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, drupal-7, outer-join

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM t1
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.wid = t1.wid
         LIMIT ' . $number . ' OFFSET 678';
```

When i change by my hand this offset it runs for different values of my database... How I can do it without change with my hand this offset?? Someone said me that I can do it without offset but he did not tell me how... Could someone help plz?? I have over a month with this issue :'( :'( :'(

Comment: You want to change that offset dynamically? Why don't you use it in for loop or something?

Comment: I want when cron runs it will runs for some number of values the number will be selected from the user.. I did it this with the number and it works but if i have only limit without offset it runs always for the same values of the database

Comment: Give us example of your manually changed code for second run. How it looks like when you change it and run again.

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT * FROM t1
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.wid = t1.wid
         LIMIT ' . $number . ' OFFSET 317';  with that it runs for some other values

Comment: And how would you like that OFFSET parameter to change? 1,2,3.... and so on, or there is some formula?

Comment: this offset maybe do not needed... I want on first run it will take e.g 0-20 on the second run 20-40 on the third 40-60 and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$per_page = 10;
$current_page = read_current_page(); // 0,1,2...
$start = $current_page*$per_page;

 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM t1
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.wid = t1.wid
         LIMIT ' . $start . ','. $per_page;
save_current_page(++$current_page);
```

It should be something like that. read_current_page() should somehow read value from file, database or where ever you decide to keep that value. So, you need some place to store it between the calls.

Then you create your query and at end you have to update value of that counter. Add also some logic to reset it, the way you need it. But point is that you have to store it somewhere outside of your code...since after call is executed all values are lost.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using LIMIT with two arguments. The first will be your starting point and the second your offset. eg:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

To adapt it to the example:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM t1
     RIGHT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.wid = t1.wid
     LIMIT ' . $number . ', 678';
```

Maybe see [MySQL: Select](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) for more help.

Comment: I do not want limits you cannot undertand?? I want to run all the values but not all together but 20-20 or 50-50 or 100-100 and this number will be the number that the user will select on a dropdown form...