# Why this sql union do not run for me?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, drupal, union

```
'SELECT * FROM t1
          LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.wid = t1.wid
          UNION
          SELECT * FROM t1
          RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t2.wid = t1.wid
          ORDER BY t2.wid
          LIMIT ' . $number;
```

Could you help me with these lines of code? I a trying over a month to solve the same problem..

Comment: What does not work ? Explain more on it. And why reference to a different table in order by  `ORDER BY watchdog.wid`

Comment: are there equal number of columns with same dataype in both query ?

Comment: in both queries i have a wid column

Comment: Are you using MySQL?

Comment: yeah i am using MySQL

Comment: You have used LEFT and RIGHT JOINS also UNION. It may avoided if you provide the table structure with sample data and desired result.

Comment: how i could avoid it?? What did you mean?

Comment: post your table structure, sample data and expected result. we will try some other method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363469/i-want-these-lines-to-run-for-all-of-the-values-of-my-database look this if you could help me i have over a month with this problem... in this link put the left union right code.. Thank you

Comment: help me with that i am near my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384809/where-is-the-fault-in-my-sql-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not explained exactly what problem you're having with the query, so we're left to guess.  As StewS2 observed, however, the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses in the original query are associated with the second subquery, not with the result of the `UNION`.  That may be your problem.  In that case, it may also be that you want to order by `t1.wid` when `t2.wid` is `NULL` (as a result of the outer join) and *vise versa*.

To associate the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses with the whole rowset, you need an inline view (such as StewS2 suggested) or a temporary table.  Either way, you have to overcome a column naming problem: each column of the join result needs a distinct name in an inline view or temp table, but you have a collision at least for the columns named `wid`.  If it's a self join then you have a collision for every column.  SQL has a solution: assign distinct column aliases.  You need to do that explicitly, however; you cannot combine it with the `*` wildcard.

Something like this could be what you're after:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  -- this is the inline view
  SELECT t1.wid AS t1_wid, t1.x, t2.wid AS t2_wid, t2.y
  FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t2.wid = t1.wid

  UNION

  SELECT t1.wid AS t1_wid, t1.x, t2.wid AS t2_wid, t2.y
  FROM t1 RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t2.wid = t1.wid
) full -- table alias required, even though it's never referenced
-- coalesce() provides the first-listed non-null value
ORDER BY COALESCE(t1_wid, t2_wid)
LIMIT 100
```

StewS2 is also right that this whole thing would be a lot easier if you could use a full join; unfortunately, MySQL does not support that.

Comment: help me with that i am near my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384809/where-is-the-fault-in-my-sql-code

Comment: John, thanks for explaining what I was saying better than I did.

Answer (score 0):

As @AbhikChakraborty alluded, you should remove the table alias "t2." from the field name in the ORDER BY clause.  You have to treat the union as if it's essentially:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *
          FROM t1
          LEFT JOIN t2
            ON t2.wid = t1.wid
        UNION
        SELECT *
          FROM t1
         RIGHT JOIN t2
            ON t2.wid = t1.wid)
LIMIT ....
 ORDER BY wid
```

So the ORDER BY clause can only reference the common field name from the subquery.  I'm not familiar with that LIMIT syntax, but I suspect it would work the same way.

Finally, depending on your mySQL capabilities, it looks like you could achieve this with a full outer join (if t1 and t2 are really the same tables).

Good luck,

Stew

Comment: full outer join could not supported from MySQL

Comment: This isn't quite going to work because there are two separate `wid` columns.  The `ORDER BY` needs to be told which to use.  Secondarily, MySQL wants all inline views to have aliases assigned, even if those aliases are never used.

Comment: help me with that i am near my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384809/where-is-the-fault-in-my-sql-code

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that both tables have a column named "wid".  So the next solution would be to not do a "SELECT *" from both tables, because you'll end up with a duplicated column name.  If you are joining on that column, then the values will be equal, so you don't have to identify to the ORDER BY clause which one you want.

So specify all the columns you want from each table and make sure to only include the "wid" column from one of the tables.

Then you can use it in the ORDER BY