# where is the fault in my sql code?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, drupal

```
'SELECT * FROM t1
          JOIN t2 ON t1.wid = t2.wid
          WHERE t2.wid IS NULL
          LIMIT ' . $number;
```

This code nothing returns to me could you help why i do not take values back??

Comment: show the table structures and what is `WHERE IS NULL` ?

Comment: i have a t1 that has many values like 2.000.000 rows and an empty t2. What i want is to run all the rows from t1 but with limit number that user will select and someone tell me that this could be solved with where is null.. And if the JOIN is not NULL the values from t1 will be inserted in t2... I solve this insert but these lines of code do not run for me :'(

Comment: Is there a policy against asking same question multiple times? This question is asked 3X so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JOIN t2 ON t1.wid = t1.wid
```

did you mean that? or do you really mean t1.wid = t2.wid? in which case you'd want a left join.

**EDIT**

Okay, so you fixed it. That won't show up any results unless there are rows in t2 that have a wid that matches a row in t1 with the same wid.

If you want results, change it to this:

```
'SELECT * FROM t1
          LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.wid = t2.wid
          WHERE t2.wid IS NULL
          LIMIT ' . $number;
```

**NEXT EDIT**

If the goal is to update t2 with values from t1 that aren't ALREADY in t2, then it would be something like this:

```
'INSERT INTO t2 
   SELECT t1.* FROM t1
     LEFT JOIN t2 
        ON t1.wid = t2.wid
     WHERE t2.wid IS NULL
     LIMIT ' . $number;
```

The missing step was simply to return only t1's results, and then insert them into t2.

Comment: i have a t1 that has many values like 2.000.000 rows and an empty t2. What i want is to run all the rows from t1 but with limit number that user will select and someone tell me that this could be solved with where is null.. And if the JOIN is not NULL the values from t1 will be inserted in t2... I solve this insert but these lines of code do not run for me :'(

Comment: @Karmen, if your `t2` is literally *empty*, and will remain that way, then there is absolutely nothing to be gained by joining it to `t1`, whether via an inner join or an outer join.

Comment: @Karmen is your requirement here to make t2 a copy of t1? but to do it only bit by bit so as not to take a long time in a single query?

Comment: I know but i want the user to select how many values want to copy....thank you so much..... I think you are the only that understand what i want to do.... could you help me?

Comment: In that case, i just updated the answer once more, and i think it will do what you want now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo.

```
'SELECT * FROM t1
              JOIN t2 ON t1.wid = t2.wid
              WHERE t2.wid IS NULL
              LIMIT ' . $number;
```